# Открыть протокол rdp для возможности подключения

Tags: bat, rdp

Есть обычный ПК, нужно чтоб к нему можно было подключаться по `rdp`. Для того чтобы вручную не вводить все команды, сделал батник

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 3389" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=3389



reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f'
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\DomainProfile\GloballyOpenPorts\List" /v 3389:TCP /t REG_SZ /d 3389:TCP:*:Enabled:@xpsp2res.dll,-22009 /f'
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile\GloballyOpenPorts\List" /v 3389:TCP /t REG_SZ /d 3389:TCP:*:Enabled:@xpsp2res.dll,-22009 /f'
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f'
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\DomainProfile\GloballyOpenPorts\List" /v 3389:TCP /t REG_SZ /d 3389:TCP:*:Enabled:@xpsp2res.dll,-22009 /f'
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile\GloballyOpenPorts\List" /v 3389:TCP /t REG_SZ /d 3389:TCP:*:Enabled:@xpsp2res.dll,-22009 /f'

REG ADD "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f'
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f'
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\DomainProfile\Services\RemoteDesktop /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f'
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\DomainProfile\Services\RemoteDesktop /v RemoteAddresses /d localsubnet /f'
```

Но компьютер так же не доступен по rdp. Не подскажите, в чем проблема ?

Comment: У ПК прямой ip? Или коннектитесь в локальной сети?

Comment: @excellproj динамический

Comment: Как минимум должен быть прямой(внешний) ip адрес у ПК к которому подключаетесь через интернет.

Comment: @excellproj можете немного по подробнее ? не совсем понял, тобишь, ip должен быть статическим для подключения к пк ? а тех изменений в системе, что я сделал (код выше), достаточно для подкл к пк по рдп, если ип будет статичным ?

Comment: Да, IP должен быть статическим.Также, если ПК находится за роутером, то нужно сделать проброс портов

Comment: [tag:delphi] тут каким боком вообще?

Comment: Вас тут сейчас запутают в край. Нет, статический адрес необязателен, динамический просто придётся каждый раз смотреть заново. Обязателен внешний, видимый снаружи. Либо проброс соответствующего порта с другой машины, такой адрес имеющей.

Comment: @D-side запускаю батник (код выше), пытаюсь подключиться по рдп к пк (получаю текущий ип), но безуспешно, пишет, что не запущен пк. Что я делаю не так ? сам пк подключен к вифи точке

Comment: @teran никаким, просто дописал :)

Comment: При просмотре портов у пк (через онлайн сайты), то порт 3389 закрыт, хотя смотрю в брандмауре и правило для порта 3389 есть, и команда `netstat -a` говорит, что порт 3389 слушается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понял из комментариев, Ваш ПК подключен к роутеру, через который он выходит в интернет. Следовательно любое входящее подключение из интернета будет к роутеру. Вам необходимо настроить проброс порта RDP на ПК. Т.е. правило на роутере, что входящее подключение по 3389 порту необходимо перенаправить на ПК с таким-то ip адресом. Настройки зависят от модели вашего сетевого устройства.
Для теста, можно попробовать подключиться к ПК по RDP с другого устройства в вашей локальной сети.

Answer (score 0):

1. Проверить работоспособность RDP (не настраивая роутер) можно из вашей сети с другого устройства
2. И если у вас домашняя версия операционной системы, то встроенный RDP может отсутствовать, но решение есть:

[RDP Wrapper Library](http://stascorp.com/load/1-1-0-63)

[Страница проекта на GitHub](https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap)

Проект существует достаточно давно. Проверен. Работает

> Данный проект позволяет включить поддержку сервера удалённых рабочих столов (RDP Host) на системах для домашнего пользования с урезанным функционалом, а также снять ограничение на использование параллельных сессий.
>
> RDP Wrapper работает в качестве прослойки между менеджером управления службами (SCM) и службой терминалов (TermService), таким образом файл termsrv.dll остаётся нетронутым. Также этот метод устойчив против обновлений Windows.

Для запуска достаточно сделать 2 пункта (но обязательно из командной строки от имени администратора)

1. Запустить install.bat
2. RDPConf.exe (тоже из командной строки) все 3 пункта зеленые — все ок!

[Обновление клиента RDP до современного](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/969084/description-of-the-remote-desktop-connection-7-0-client-update-for-rem)
, для системы с которой будете подключаться. (ссылка может пригодится если будет желание обновить клиентскую систему)